# Div with variable width

Tags: css, html

how I can create 3 div, div1 with max-width of 1280px, div2 and div3 with fixed width (34px and 311px) with some space among themselves.
I need to create an effect like this

----------------------------    ----    -----------
|div1                                                  |    |div2|  |div3       |
 ----------------------------    ----    -----------

and div1 can change its width when window resize.
Parent container is 1650px.

Comment: it's very bad you didn't made any effort, but here's [my example](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/R4xsA/) the idea is to put second and third div into one more div with table-cell display. If parent container has fixed width of 1650xp, and 2nd and 3rd divs are also fixed, this means that 1st div is 1650-34-311 px, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use floatting propertiesby  reversing the flow of your containers.

Or use the display properties that HTML `<table>` uses.( nothing like saying use table ;) )

HTML

```
<div id="tablelike"><!-- make these div behave like table and td elements -->
  <div class="div1">A</div>
  <div class="div2">B</div>
  <div class="div3">C</div>
</div>
<!-- reverse flow to use float properties -->
<div id="floatchild">
  <div class="div3">C</div>
  <div class="div2">B</div>
  <div class="div1">A</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#tablelike {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
    border-spacing:0.5em;
}
#tablelike, #floatchild {
  max-width:1650px;

}
#tablelike > div {
  display:table-cell;
}
.div1 {
 /* take space left */
    border:solid 1px;
}
.div2 {
  width:34px;
    border:solid 1px;
}
.div3 {
  width:311px;
    border:solid 1px;
}
#floatchild {
  padding-right:0.5em;
}
#floatchild > div {
  margin:0 0 0 0.5em;
  overflow:hidden;
}
#floatchild .div2, #floatchild .div3 {
  float:right;
}
```

there is difference of behavior, float and layout on non floatting element will allow element to stand aside each other as long as there's room for it.

table properties will keep 3 element on the same row, width same height but can allow each one to grow over size declared in CSS.

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EmlhB

Answer (score -1):

Having fixed pixel size won't give you a fluid structure when the window re-sizes.

use like this

```
.div1 {
  width: 70%;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  } 

.div2 {
  width: 5%;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  } 

.div3 {
  width: 20%;
  float:left;
  display:block;
  }
```

Hope helps this

Comment: why do you float them to the left?

Comment: @Leo Just for the grid structure

Comment: well, to display the divs beside each other you don't need to take them out of the normal flow by floating them...displaying them inline-block will do it

Comment: @winnyboy5 he meant `display:inline-block`, not `display:block`